# How to implement a dirac delta as input signal for this system

Tags: filter, signal-processing, matlab, delta

```
y[n] = b0x[n] +b1x[n-1]
```

I have this MA filter in matlab as following

```
 load handel;
 x = y;

 b0 = 0.5;
 b1 = 0.5;

 N = length(x); % Length of input signal
 y = zeros(1,20); % Allocate space for output

 y(1) = b0*x(1); % First sample, assuming x(0) = 0
  for n=2:N % Remaining samples
    y(n) = b0*x(n) + b1*x(n-1);

  end;

 soundsc(y,Fs);
```

I was asked to create an input signal `x[n] = dirac[n]` where i save the `x[n]` for `n = 0...19` in a vector and plot both signals in the same window for `axis ([-1 20 ,0 1.5])`.

I have tried so far that the new signal should look like this `y1(n) = b0*dirac(n) + b1*dirac(n-1)` but not sure if this is the right way or I maybe just not understood something?

Comment: well, if you put an impulse through a system, you get the impulse response, in your case `[b0, b1]`.

Comment: does it mean that it looks like `h[n] = b0 + b1`?

Comment: how about [impulse](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/impulse.html)?

Comment: @Adam no. I meant exactly what I wrote! The impulse response of your system has length 2 and is the vector `[b0, b1]`.

Comment: I mean, do it on paper. If you input `1,0,0,0,0,0…` to your `y[n] = b0 * x[n] + b1 * x[n-1]`, you simply get `[b0, b1, 0, …]` out. That's what we call impulse response. Because it's the response to an impulse. Since you're a student of something related to signal processing, you should be getting yourself *really* familiar with impulse responses and basics of system theory!

Comment: @MarcusMüller can you give me some hint about implementation of this signal  in matlab.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you understand matlab basics. Read a tutorial. If "`1,0,0,0,0`" doesn't translate into matlab code (hint: it already is valid matlab), then you really need to read a Matlab basics tutorial. Also, as said thrice now: No need to run this code. the result is clear.

Answer (score 1):

The output sequence y(n) is a [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) of the input sequence x(n) which "keeps memory" of the last 2 samples of the input to compute the output.

Allocating the sequence x(n), required being a [dirac pulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), into an array x[n] is a correct begin. Then you can develop the output sequence y(n) per input sequence x(n). For that I suggest you to exploit the functionality of matlab and to avoid the for loop:

```
y = zeros(1,20); % Allocate space for output
y(1) = b0*x(1); %initial condition
y(2:20) = b0*x(2:20) + b1*x(1:20); % for n > 0
```

You should obtain an array of 20 samples of y(n) that you can easily plot using the function `plot(x,y)`.
Note: since the dirac function is symbolic, you must decide by your own at which time the pulse should rise (e.g. at n=0 or otherwise). For that I suggest you the example in the [documentation of the function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/dirac.html) called "Plot Dirac Delta Function".